# Upgrading Jekyll and dependencies for github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I originally installed my local github pages through the wizard/web interface that Github pages offered.

I'm now stuck with older versions of Jekyll and dependencies in my Gemfile.lock:

https://github.com/bram-atmire/bram-atmire.github.io/blob/master/Gemfile.lock

The ruby gem github-pages gives me a clue as what the most recent versions are:
https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages

But what's the recommended way to perform these upgrades? Can I just manually update the version number for any dependency? Or is there a trick to just get the last, standardized Gemfile?

Answer (score 10):

Delete you **Gemfile.lock** and run a `bundle update` command.

You will get up to date dependencies.

In the future, you can simply use `bundle update` to update your dependencies.

Comment: thanks I will try that. But I have never built/ran this site/application locally so will also investigate how to do that.

Comment: did you find way to do that?

Comment: Bundler attempted to update github-pages but its version stayed the same